# How do you explain the statement - "as heat flows from the core of a star outwards, said core heats up and the shell cools down"?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, astrophysics

<sub>Excuse my poor English, I speak French.</sub>

---

Core Collapse in a Self-Gravitating System:

- Suppose there was no energy generation in the core. The pressure
  would still be high and the core would be hotter than the envelope.
- Energy would escape (via radiation, convection etc.) and so, the core
  would shrink a bit under gravity
- That would make it even hotter and then, even more energy would
  escape; the cycle continues in a feedback loop

Why? Why the process would make it hotter than before? The core will collapse unless an energy source is present to compensate for the escaping energy.

Imagine a particle that had moved inward. Since it was swimming in the direction of the current of gravity, the particle picked up speed as it fell and therefore gained kinetic energy. Suddenly, it collides with a more energetic particle coming from the center that deflects its trajectory. It now moves outwards. It ends up hitting a less energetic particle coming from the exterior, which causes it to return to the center. It thus lost energy. Why will it warm the core more than before by going back?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If something makes the fusion core of a star suddenly get hotter, the core expands, becomes less dense, and the rate of fusion decreases. this makes the core cool off. Conversely, if the core suddenly cools down, it contracts, gets denser, and the fusion rate goes up, making the core get hotter. This is a powerful *negative* feedback system which makes the star self-regulating and stable against perturbations.

Note that heat transfer in the core of a star is *not* by radiation, because the core is *opaque* to radiation. It is by conduction and convection, which are much, much slower processes. This means on short timescales, excess fusion heat is trapped in the core and cannot get out easily, and thus causes the core to expand and become less dense- which turns down the fusion rate and shortly makes the core cool down a bit.

Now let's take the case of a gravitating cloud, before fusion is ignited. we model the system as a point mass with lumps of matter in orbit around it. If we attach rocket motors to those lumps to speed them up a bit, they shift out to orbits of greater diameter and while doing so, they *slow down* since it takes less speed to maintain orbit farther out from the gravitating central mass. So, by adding energy to the system, it *cools down* (that is, it moves more slowly).

Systems like this which cool down when you add energy and heat up when you remove energy are called *anti-thermodynamic*.

Comment: Hello. I am asking for a kinetic theory explanation of the negative specific heat of self-gravitating matter.

Comment: Please look at the details.

Comment: If energy escape (via radiation. convection) and the core shrink, why that would make it even hotter than before? Is it because of the uncertainty principle?

Comment: I know that by releasing energy to the upper layers, the particles will begin to migrate towards the center and will eventually regain kinetic energy, but that does not explain why the core will be hotter than before.

Comment: There is a mechanism that I cannot grasp, that is to say that by releasing energy, the heart heats up more...

Comment: That would make it even hotter, and then even more energy would escape; and so on, in a feedback loop WHY???

Comment: the rate of fusion reactions occurring in the core determines the temperature there. increasing the density of the core causes an increase in the rate of fusion reactions, so denser leads to hotter, but hotter will force the core to expand, which then reduces the core density and therefore the rate of fusion reactions, and so the core then cools down. up, down, up, down- these two influences are in balance in a normal star, and so the star runs at a constant temperature.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I'm asking about a self-gravitating matter (before fusion reactions occur),  the first stages of a star formation before the ignition of nuclear reactions.

Comment: OK priscilla, I will rewrite my answer. -NN

Comment: Thank you very much, Niels Nielsen, for the time you devote to me.

Comment: It does not explain why the heart heats up more and more by releasing energy to the outer layers…

Comment: https://qr.ae/pv6evH (if we don't model the system as a point mass with lumps of matter in orbit around it.)

Comment: What obsesses me is why as the core (which is not yet the scene of fusion reactions) releases energy, it heats up more, in other words, it becomes hotter than before releasing  energy.

Comment: it heats up because gravity is compressing it. remember that H and He are not good at radiating away infrared energy, so the gravitational compression work that is converted into heat at the center has no way to get out. This trapped heat slows down the rate of gravitational compression and acts against star formation in the first generation of stars where there are no heavier elements around to get pulled into new star formation.

Answer (score 4):

The process comes about as a consequence of the [Virial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem). In its simplest form, the theorem says that the kinetic energy ($K$) of a gravitationally bound system in equilibrium is equal to half the magnitude of the gravitational potential energy ($\Omega$, which is negative) of the system.
$$ 2K + \Omega = 0$$

Meanwhile, the total energy of a system will clearly be the sum of the kinetic energy and gravitational potential energy.
$$ E = K + \Omega = \frac{\Omega}{2} ,$$
which will also be negative if the star is bound.

If the energy is lost, such that $\Delta E$ is negative, then for a new equilibrium $\Delta \Omega$ must be negative too. i.e. The star becomes more bound by becoming more compact.

But from the Virial theorem, we can see that if $\Omega$ becomes *more negative* then $K$ must *increase*. i.e. The average kinetic energy of the particles increases and in a perfect gas, that means the temperature must increase too.

As to *why* the Virial theorem is true - the general proof is quite lengthy and given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem#Statement_and_derivation). For the specific case of a gas cloud in hydrostatic equilibrium we can say that the pressure gradient balances gravitational forces as
$$ \frac{dP}{dr} = = -\frac{Gm(r)\rho}{r^2}\ , $$
where $\rho$ is the density and $m(r)$ is the mass inside radius $r$.

The total gravitational potential energy for a cloud of radius $R$ is given by the following integral
$$\Omega = - \int^{R}_0 \frac{G m(r) \rho}{r} 4\pi r^2\ dr\ ,$$
and using the equation of hydrostatic equilibrium, this is
$$\Omega = \int^{R}_0 \frac{dP}{dr}4\pi r^3\ dr$$
Integrating by parts and setting $4\pi r^2\ dr$ to be a volume element $dV$, we have
$$3\int P\ dV + \Omega = 0\ .$$
This is indeed a statement of the Virial theorem because the kinetic energy of an ideal gas is given by
$$ K = \frac{2}{3}\int P\ dV\ . $$

Comment: You are right. https://youtu.be/ULYK_9NwN28